# How to go beyond django.contrib.admin to handle security concerns and model grouping?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a need to do the following with django:

1. Make models available for CRUD in django, securing available CRUD operations and models based on user's role.
2. Provide a way of grouping models on the main `/admin/` page so that when many models are displayed, a user can drill down easily.  Right now they're grouped by app (since I have one app and it has one models.py file).
3. I would like to use a different theme for the django admin UI.  I'm not sure if django admin tools is the right thing for this.

I want to write as little code as possible.

What's the best way to do these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). I'd be wary about themeing the admin site too dramatically though, as it could become very difficult with things like i1l8 and built in javascript.

The other, more extreme way, would be looking into a different admin app entirely like [nexus](http://code.disqus.com/code/projects/nexus.html), and tailoring it to how you'd like.